# Javascript: Lexical and execution scope

Tags: javascript

Just trying to wrap scoping around my head :-)

How can I refactor this code in order to be able to output 
`'a', 'b' and 'c'` within function `third()`?

Any explanation without confusion and unnecessary theory would help.

```js
var a = 1;

first = () => {
  let b = 2;
  second = () => {
    let c = 3;
    console.log(a, b); // Output 1, 2
    third(); // Output 1, 2, 3
  }
  console.log(a); // Output 1
  second();
}

third = () => {
  console.log(a, b, c);
}

first();
```

Comment: pass the variables as an argument to `third`

Comment: As you defined `second()` inside `first()`, do the same for `third()` inside `second()`. which is [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Answer (score 1):

b is not defined in the scope of the function third(). You will also get the same error for c. If you move the definition of third inside of second it will gain access to the scope of first and second since it would become a closure of them and then you will get expected behavior.

```js
var a = 1;

first = () => {
  let b = 2;
  second = () => {
    let c = 3;
    console.log(a, b); // Output 1, 2
    third = () => {
        console.log(a, b, c);
    }
    third(); // Output 1, 2, 3
  }
  console.log(a); // Output 1
  second();
}


first();
```

EDIT: Typo

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is to simple make all three variables global by defining them outside of any function and just fill them with values when you need to.

```js
var a = 1;
let b;
let c;

first = () => {
  b = 2;
  second = () => {
    c = 3;
    console.log(a, b); // Output 1, 2
    third(); // Output 1, 2, 3
  }
  console.log(a); // Output 1
  second();
}

third = () => {
  console.log(a, b, c);
}

first();
```

Comment: Hi Sebastian, and thanks for quick answers.
That was my first (beginner approach) but I was hoping a different method just to fully understand lexical and execution scope. Maybe I'm just making things more complicated than they need to be :)
Is there a way to not declare the variables in the global scope and still access them?

Comment: @gurvinder372 explains two other solutions which aren't polluting the global scope

Answer (score 0):

Hope, this is what you are looking for =>

```
var a = 1, b, c;

first = () => {
    b = 2;
    second = () => {
        c = 3;
        console.log(a, b); // Output 1, 2
        third(); // Output 1, 2, 3
     }
    console.log(a); // Output 1
    second();
}

third = () => {
    console.log(a, b, c);
}

first();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Any explanation without confusion and unnecessary theory would help

`b` and `c` are not locally scoped to `first`, so **either** define `third` where `b` and `c` are accessible

```
var a = 1;

first = () => {
  let b = 2;
  second = () => {
    let c = 3;
    console.log(a, b); 
    third = () => { //defined it inside second
      console.log(a, b, c);
    };
    third(); 
  }
  console.log(a); 
  second();
}

first();
```

Or, pass `a`, `b` and `c` as an argument to `third` while invoking the same.

```
var a = 1;

first = () => {
  let b = 2;
  second = () => {
    let c = 3;
    console.log(a, b);
    third(a,b,c); // pass a, b and c as parameters
  }
  console.log(a); 
  second();
}

third = (a,b,c) => { //accept a, b and c
  console.log(a, b, c);
}

first();
```

Answer (score 0):

In comments it's written right that you have to pass your variables. Function third has an access to the variable `a` but not to `b` and `c`, since they are scoped locally in function `first` and `second`.

Functions look for a variable within themselves, then within parent and so on towards the global.

So function `second` contains variable `c`, but not `a` and `b`. It looks within it's parent which has variable `b` and then global variable `a`. However, function `third` is not nested, so the next scope it looks for a variable is global scope which contains **only** variable `a`